# Maximum perimeter of an isosceles triangle inscribed in the unit circle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

So I have seen this question asked before but with variations (circle of radius 4, and an equilateral triangle) and so I am hoping for an answer on how to do this.

After looking around I saw that people assume that the maximum perimeter of such a triangle is equilateral, meaning you have all the degrees. I wanted to ask how to actually prove that or something. I was given this problem on an exam and I usually sit down and do them just because I like solving these kinds of problems but I couldn't get it to work because I got too many messy equations and I had no time to clean up. What I'd like to ask is what is the best way of solving this, if you don't assume this?

When I tried to solve it I thought that I could do it like I would do with a square:

Find an equation

```
 f(x) = 2*(sqrt((1 - cos x)² + sin² x) + sin x)  => perimeter
```

and then get

```
f'(x) = 0
```

and find what angle would satisfy those conditions. What I got though is a mess of trigonometric stuff that I found impossible to solve (my memory is bad so I easily forget formulas for trig. functions).

Anyway, was I doing the right thing but I may have messed up with the formulas or is there something I could do instead?

Visually what I did was thinking of the triangle's height being the x-coordinate from $x = 1$, so with an angle of $2\pi/3$ I get height = 1½ for example. And then the base would be just $\sin{  (2\pi/3)} = \sqrt{3}/2$

Anyway, that was just an example to try to explain how I was thinking when I set the equation up. I bet there's a better way that I'm not seeing. And I want to know how to prove things so if you want to tell me something like "this is always true for ..." please give me a link to an/or explanation of why that is so.

Comment: Isosceles triangle include equilaterals right? Then, there are proofs for this, let me search for one.

Comment: Work with the angles at the centre of the circle to the points of the triangle. A general inscribed triangle is given by 3 angles which must add to 360. Write down the perimeter in terms of these angles and maximise with respect to the two angles. Gives you two simple equations to solve.

Comment: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/InscribedEquilateral.shtml

Comment: Okey thanks guys I'll look it up once I'm done with the current one I'm solving :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought an image could help: 
[image]

The perimeter is $$\overline{BC} + 2\overline{AB} = 2\sin \alpha + 2\cdot 2\sin \beta = 2\sin \alpha + 2\cdot 2\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\alpha}{2}\right) = 2\left(\sin \alpha+2\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2} \right) \right)$$
For further simplifications let $\alpha = 2t$, then you have to maximize $$f(t) = 2\left(\sin 2t+2\cos t) \right) = 2(2\sin t \cos t + 2\cos t ) = 4(\sin t \cos t + \cos t) $$
Finding $f'(t)$ is easy: $f'(t) = 4(\cos t \cdot \cos t + \sin t \cdot -\sin t -\sin t) = 4(\cos^2 t - \sin^2 t -\sin t )=4(-2\sin^2 t -\sin t +1)$ and it equals $0$ when $\sin t = \frac12 \Rightarrow  t = \frac{\pi}{6} \Rightarrow \alpha = 2t = \frac{\pi}{3} $ so the triangle is equilater!