# What is the largest possible perimeter of a triangle whose sides have integer lengths and that can fit inside a circle of radius $20$ cm?

Tags: geometry, contest-math

This question was asked in last year's "Mathcounts" competition.

What is the largest possible perimeter of a triangle whose sides have integer lengths and that can fit inside a circle of radius $20$ cm?

This is a question from a recent math contest.  I was thinking that I should start by considering a circumcircle of the triangle with a circumradius $19<R<20$.  (If that doesn't work I'd go smaller.)

I started by considering an equilateral triangle just because it would be easy to express $R$ in terms of the triangle side length, $s$.    $R =\frac{s}{\sqrt 3}$.

Substituting into the above chain inequality yields $19<\frac{s}{\sqrt 3}<20$.  So approximating, $33\leq s \leq 34$.

So I've got a ballpark size of my triangle, but I'm not sure how to proceed.  This contest does allow the use of a calculator.

Comment: What is the source and date of the question?

Comment: Last year's national mathcounts.

Comment: Thanks!  I'd suggest you edit your post to include that information.  Thanks for responding so quickly!

Answer (score 1):

The largest possible perimeter of  triangle with circumradius $20$ occurs when the triangle is equilateral and has sides of length $34.64$. So we know we can get a perimeter of $3\times 34=102$ and that we cannot get a perimeter of $3\times 34.64=103.9$

All you have to check is the circumradius of a $34,34,35$ triangle.

I get $19.82$ so $34,34,35$ is the triangle with the largest perimeter.

Comment: Is it easy to see that the largest perimeter of all triangles with the same circumradius $r$ is of an equilateral triangle with that circumradius (and therefore with the side $r\sqrt{3}$)? I am sure this is true btw, but just curious if the proof is easy.

Comment: Yes - fairly easy. I think the answer of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710796/maximum-perimeter-of-an-isosceles-triangle-inscribed-in-the-unit-circle?noredirect=1&lq=1 is a good one.

Comment: Yuck, trigonometry + derivatives. (I would prefer an elementary proof. But this is a personal preference.)

Comment: I think I vaguely remember a neat purely geometrical proof but I would need time to work it out again!

Comment: @StinkingBishop. Keeping an edge and the sum of the other two edges constant generates an ellipse containing the circumcircle. So the maximum has to occur when all sides are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose:

R is radius of circle

S is the area of triangle

a, b and c are the measure of the sides

We may use this formula:

$$4RS=abc$$

R is known to be constant, If S is maximum abc will be maximum and it is possible only if $a=b=c$.Hence perimeter will be maximum if a=b=c and we can write:

$R=20$

$$S=\frac{\sqrt 3}4 a^2$$

$$4\times 20\times \frac{\sqrt 3}4 a^2=a^3$$

which gives:

$a\approx 34.6$

and perimeter is:

$$p=3\times 34.6\approx 104$$

Closest integers are :

$$(a, b, c)=(33, 34, 35)$$

Comment: I should have included the actual answer is 103.   But this approach is very helpful.